# SOAPUI unable to display the function name included in wsdl

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I had created a wsdl as shown below using zend framework

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"     xmlns:tns="http://soap.loc/index/soap" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Example_Manager" targetNamespace="http://soap.loc/index/soap">
<types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://soap.loc/index/soap">
        <xsd:element name="getProducts">
            <xsd:complexType/>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="getProductsResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="getProductsResult" type="soap-enc:Array"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="getProduct">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="getProductResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="getProductResult" type="soap-enc:Array"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="addProduct">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="data" type="soap-enc:Array"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="addProductResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="addProductResult" type="xsd:int"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="deleteProduct">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="deleteProductResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="deleteProductResult" type="xsd:int"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="updateProduct">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="data" type="soap-enc:Array"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="updateProductResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="updateProductResult" type="xsd:int"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
<portType name="Example_ManagerPort">
    <operation name="getProducts">
        <documentation>Returns list of all products in database</documentation>
        <input message="tns:getProductsIn"/>
        <output message="tns:getProductsOut"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getProduct">
        <documentation>Returns specified product in database</documentation>
        <input message="tns:getProductIn"/>
        <output message="tns:getProductOut"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="addProduct">
        <documentation>Adds new product to database</documentation>
        <input message="tns:addProductIn"/>
        <output message="tns:addProductOut"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="deleteProduct">
        <documentation>Deletes product from database</documentation>
        <input message="tns:deleteProductIn"/>
        <output message="tns:deleteProductOut"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="updateProduct">
        <documentation>Updates product in database</documentation>
        <input message="tns:updateProductIn"/>
        <output message="tns:updateProductOut"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="Example_ManagerBinding" type="tns:Example_ManagerPort">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://framework.zend.com"/>
    <operation name="getProducts">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://soap.loc/index/soap#getProducts"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://framework.zend.com"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://framework.zend.com"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getProduct">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://soap.loc/index/soap#getProduct"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://framework.zend.com"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://framework.zend.com"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="addProduct">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://soap.loc/index/soap#addProduct"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://framework.zend.com"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://framework.zend.com"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="deleteProduct">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://soap.loc/index/soap#deleteProduct"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://framework.zend.com"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://framework.zend.com"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="updateProduct">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://soap.loc/index/soap#updateProduct"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://framework.zend.com"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://framework.zend.com"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="Example_ManagerService">
    <port name="Example_ManagerPort" binding="tns:Example_ManagerBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://soap.loc/index/soap"/>
    </port>
</service>
<message name="getProductsIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getProducts"/>
</message>
<message name="getProductsOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getProductsResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="getProductIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getProduct"/>
</message>
<message name="getProductOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getProductResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="addProductIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:addProduct"/>
</message>
<message name="addProductOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:addProductResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="deleteProductIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:deleteProduct"/>
</message>
<message name="deleteProductOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:deleteProductResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="updateProductIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:updateProduct"/>
</message>
<message name="updateProductOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:updateProductResponse"/>
</message>
```

Now the problem is that when i load this in soapui, function names are not being displayed.
Earlier I had a working wsdl using NuSoap, which generated wsdl and could be loaded into SOAPUi and function names were being displayed.

New into web service business, It would be great to know if its wrong with the wsdl itself.

Banging my head on the monitor to get an answer ....... but only things i see is stars.

Comment: I changed     <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://framework.zend.com"/> to <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/> and the function names are getting displayed .......... now it is saying ....... SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Could not find any usable binding services in WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, you have missed a tag in your wsdl. It's not correct.
Save your wsdl in form of xml and if you will open it in web browser, you will find the error.

Comment: </definitions> This tag is missing in your wsdl :P. Add it at the end of your wsdl. It will be alright buddy. Thanks,ambuj

Comment: Thank you for the answer @user3090039 ..... it was my mistake that i had left the closure of definition tag while posting ..... but for my trouble there was an issue with the transport itself ........ which was managed ......... thanks for the reply .......... :)